# Make Ripple Buttons clickable with Javascript & CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have found a Script which makes an animation while click on Button. The Problem is, it doesn't redirect to link.

```js
(function() { var cleanUp, debounce, i, len, ripple, rippleContainer, ripples, showRipple;

debounce = function(func, delay) {
  var inDebounce;
  inDebounce = undefined;
  return function() {
    var args, context;
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(inDebounce);
    return inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
      return func.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
};

showRipple = function(e) {
  var pos, ripple, rippler, size, style, x, y;
  ripple = this;
  rippler = document.createElement('span');
  size = ripple.offsetWidth;
  pos = ripple.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.pageX - pos.left - (size / 2);
  y = e.pageY - pos.top - (size / 2);
  style = 'top:' + y + 'px; left: ' + x + 'px; height: ' + size + 'px; width: ' + size + 'px;';
  ripple.rippleContainer.appendChild(rippler);
  return rippler.setAttribute('style', style);
};

cleanUp = function() {
  while (this.rippleContainer.firstChild) {
    this.rippleContainer.removeChild(this.rippleContainer.firstChild);
  }
};

ripples = document.querySelectorAll('[ripple]');

for (i = 0, len = ripples.length; i < len; i++) {
  ripple = ripples[i];
  rippleContainer = document.createElement('div');
  rippleContainer.className = 'ripple--container';
  ripple.addEventListener('mousedown', showRipple);
  ripple.addEventListener('mouseup', debounce(cleanUp, 2000));
  ripple.rippleContainer = rippleContainer;
  ripple.appendChild(rippleContainer);
}
 }());
```

```css
.bg--red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.tx--red {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
.bg--blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}
.tx--blue {
  color: #00f;
}
.bg--green {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.tx--green {
  color: #2ecc71;
}
.bg--white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.tx--white {
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
button {
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
button:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px #000;
}
[ripple] {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
[ripple] .ripple--container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
[ripple] .ripple--container span {
  transform: scale(0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.75;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: ripple 1000ms;
}
@-moz-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a  class="bg--red tx--white" ripple="ripple" href="http://www.google.de">Fail</a>
  <button class="bg--blue tx--white" ripple="ripple">Info</button>
  <button class="bg--green tx--white" ripple="ripple">Save</button>
</div>
```

I want to make the Button Clickable. If you Click on one of the Buttons it should redirect to Link.

My solution would be to add an javascript redirect function but I don't want it. I want to make it possible with `<a href="">`

I would be glad if someone has an solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function() { var cleanUp, debounce, i, len, ripple, rippleContainer, ripples, showRipple;

debounce = function(func, delay) {
  var inDebounce;
  inDebounce = undefined;
  return function() {
    var args, context;
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(inDebounce);
    return inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
      return func.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
};

showRipple = function(e) {
  var pos, ripple, rippler, size, style, x, y;
  ripple = this;
  rippler = document.createElement('span');
  size = ripple.offsetWidth;
  pos = ripple.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.pageX - pos.left - (size / 2);
  y = e.pageY - pos.top - (size / 2);
  style = 'top:' + y + 'px; left: ' + x + 'px; height: ' + size + 'px; width: ' + size + 'px;';
  ripple.rippleContainer.appendChild(rippler);
  return rippler.setAttribute('style', style);
};

cleanUp = function() {
  while (this.rippleContainer.firstChild) {
    this.rippleContainer.removeChild(this.rippleContainer.firstChild);
  }
};

ripples = document.querySelectorAll('[ripple]');

for (i = 0, len = ripples.length; i < len; i++) {
  ripple = ripples[i];
  rippleContainer = document.createElement('div');
  rippleContainer.className = 'ripple--container';
  ripple.addEventListener('mousedown', showRipple);
  ripple.addEventListener('mouseup', debounce(cleanUp, 2000));
  ripple.rippleContainer = rippleContainer;
  ripple.appendChild(rippleContainer);
}
 }());
```

```css
.bg--red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.tx--red {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
.bg--blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}
.tx--blue {
  color: #00f;
}
.bg--green {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.tx--green {
  color: #2ecc71;
}
.bg--white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.tx--white {
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
button,a { /* style the anchor as a button */
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
button:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px #000;
}
[ripple] {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
[ripple] .ripple--container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
[ripple] .ripple--container span {
  transform: scale(0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.75;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: ripple 1000ms;
}
@-moz-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a  class="bg--red tx--white" ripple="ripple" href="http://www.google.de">Fail</a>
  <button class="bg--blue tx--white" ripple="ripple">Info</button>
  
  <!-- change this to anchor -->
  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="bg--green tx--white" ripple="ripple">Save</a>
  
  
</div>
```

Try Styling your anchor element as a button. made some changes to html and css.. check this

Comment: Make a Default Html Page and test it there it will not work

Comment: @ElyasNice, it is working .. I have edited the href. give this one a try

Comment: Nop, it doesnt redirect. @chandra-shekhar

Comment: i have tried it on my local system. chrome browser. May i know which browser are you using, bcoz that worked for me. check the href of the anchor element

Comment: Have added the Html Code after javascript. It redirect but doest show the animation

Comment: add css before body and script tags after it should work fine. can you create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net

Comment: [link](https://www.deinkleinanzeigen.de/wa.php) Have Upload your Code. Look the Ripple  Effect doesnt appear

Comment: console is showing the error . you missed part of js code plz check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185004/discussion-between-elyas-nice-and-chandra-shekhar).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `<a>` around `<button>`

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
   

 (function() { var cleanUp, debounce, i, len, ripple, rippleContainer, ripples, showRipple;

debounce = function(func, delay) {
  var inDebounce;
  inDebounce = undefined;
  return function() {
    var args, context;
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(inDebounce);
    return inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
      return func.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
};

showRipple = function(e) {
  var pos, ripple, rippler, size, style, x, y;
  ripple = this;
  rippler = document.createElement('span');
  size = ripple.offsetWidth;
  pos = ripple.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.pageX - pos.left - (size / 2);
  y = e.pageY - pos.top - (size / 2);
  style = 'top:' + y + 'px; left: ' + x + 'px; height: ' + size + 'px; width: ' + size + 'px;';
  ripple.rippleContainer.appendChild(rippler);
  return rippler.setAttribute('style', style);
};

cleanUp = function() {
  while (this.rippleContainer.firstChild) {
    this.rippleContainer.removeChild(this.rippleContainer.firstChild);
  }
};

ripples = document.querySelectorAll('[ripple]');

for (i = 0, len = ripples.length; i < len; i++) {
  ripple = ripples[i];
  rippleContainer = document.createElement('div');
  rippleContainer.className = 'ripple--container';
  ripple.addEventListener('mousedown', showRipple);
  ripple.addEventListener('mouseup', debounce(cleanUp, 2000));
  ripple.rippleContainer = rippleContainer;
  ripple.appendChild(rippleContainer);
}
 }());
```

```css
    .bg--red {
      background-color: #e74c3c;
    }
    .tx--red {
      color: #e74c3c;
    }
    .bg--blue {
      background-color: #00f;
    }
    .tx--blue {
      color: #00f;
    }
    .bg--green {
      background-color: #2ecc71;
    }
    .tx--green {
      color: #2ecc71;
    }
    .bg--white {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    .tx--white {
      color: #fff;
    }
    body {
      color: #777;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0 0 0 0;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    button {
      border: none;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 10px;
      font-size: 14px;
      outline: 0;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #000;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    button:active {
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px #000;
    }
    [ripple] {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    [ripple] .ripple--container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    [ripple] .ripple--container span {
      transform: scale(0);
      border-radius: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0.75;
      background-color: #fff;
      animation: ripple 1000ms;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes ripple {
      to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(2);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes ripple {
      to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(2);
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes ripple {
      to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(2);
      }
    }
    @keyframes ripple {
      to {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(2);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
      <a  class="bg--red tx--white" ripple="ripple" href="http://www.google.de">Fail</a>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><button class="bg--blue tx--white" ripple="ripple">Info</button></a>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><button class="bg--green tx--white" ripple="ripple">Save</button></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: It doesnt work  and I have buttons with a href. I cant add it twice also <a href=""> <a href=""> Fail </a> </a>

Comment: @jyme Make a Default Html Page and test it there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .... it will not work here because stackoverflow disabled the redirection....

```js
(function() { var cleanUp, debounce, i, len, ripple, rippleContainer, ripples, showRipple;

$('.bg--blue').on('click',function(){
window.open("https://stactoverflow.com")
})
$('.bg--green').on('click',function(){
window.open("https://stactoverflow.com")
})

debounce = function(func, delay) {
  var inDebounce;
  inDebounce = undefined;
  return function() {
    var args, context;
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(inDebounce);
    return inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
      return func.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
};

showRipple = function(e) {
  var pos, ripple, rippler, size, style, x, y;
  ripple = this;
  rippler = document.createElement('span');
  size = ripple.offsetWidth;
  pos = ripple.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.pageX - pos.left - (size / 2);
  y = e.pageY - pos.top - (size / 2);
  style = 'top:' + y + 'px; left: ' + x + 'px; height: ' + size + 'px; width: ' + size + 'px;';
  ripple.rippleContainer.appendChild(rippler);
  return rippler.setAttribute('style', style);
};

cleanUp = function() {
  while (this.rippleContainer.firstChild) {
    this.rippleContainer.removeChild(this.rippleContainer.firstChild);
  }
};

ripples = document.querySelectorAll('[ripple]');

for (i = 0, len = ripples.length; i < len; i++) {
  ripple = ripples[i];
  rippleContainer = document.createElement('div');
  rippleContainer.className = 'ripple--container';
  ripple.addEventListener('mousedown', showRipple);
  ripple.addEventListener('mouseup', debounce(cleanUp, 2000));
  ripple.rippleContainer = rippleContainer;
  ripple.appendChild(rippleContainer);
}
 }());
```

```css
.bg--red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.tx--red {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
.bg--blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}
.tx--blue {
  color: #00f;
}
.bg--green {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.tx--green {
  color: #2ecc71;
}
.bg--white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.tx--white {
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
button {
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
button:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px #000;
}
[ripple] {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
[ripple] .ripple--container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
[ripple] .ripple--container span {
  transform: scale(0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.75;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: ripple 1000ms;
}
@-moz-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <a  class="bg--red tx--white" ripple="ripple" href="http://www.google.de">Fail</a>
  <button class="bg--blue tx--white" ripple="ripple">Info</button>
  <button class="bg--green tx--white" ripple="ripple">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a Solution but I will not make a javascript redirect code for each button

Comment: why you are using button within <a> tag ? try applying css classes on buttons.. that will work

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to the following

```js
(function() { var cleanUp, debounce, i, len, ripple, rippleContainer, ripples, showRipple;

debounce = function(func, delay) {
  var inDebounce;
  inDebounce = undefined;
  return function() {
    var args, context;
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(inDebounce);
    return inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
      return func.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
};

showRipple = function(e) {
  var pos, ripple, rippler, size, style, x, y;
  ripple = this;
  rippler = document.createElement('span');
  size = ripple.offsetWidth;
  pos = ripple.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.pageX - pos.left - (size / 2);
  y = e.pageY - pos.top - (size / 2);
  style = 'top:' + y + 'px; left: ' + x + 'px; height: ' + size + 'px; width: ' + size + 'px;';
  ripple.rippleContainer.appendChild(rippler);
  return rippler.setAttribute('style', style);
};

cleanUp = function() {
  while (this.rippleContainer.firstChild) {
    this.rippleContainer.removeChild(this.rippleContainer.firstChild);
  }
};

ripples = document.querySelectorAll('[ripple]');

for (i = 0, len = ripples.length; i < len; i++) {
  ripple = ripples[i];
  rippleContainer = document.createElement('div');
  rippleContainer.className = 'ripple--container';
  ripple.addEventListener('mousedown', showRipple);
  ripple.addEventListener('mouseup', debounce(cleanUp, 2000));
  ripple.rippleContainer = rippleContainer;
  ripple.appendChild(rippleContainer);
}
 }());
```

```css
.bg--red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.tx--red {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
.bg--blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}
.tx--blue {
  color: #00f;
}
.bg--green {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.tx--green {
  color: #2ecc71;
}
.bg--white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.tx--white {
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}
a {/**change the style on the link not the button**/
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration:none;/**remove the link underline**/
}
a:active {/**probabily don't need this**/
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px #000;
}
[ripple] {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
[ripple] .ripple--container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
[ripple] .ripple--container span {
  transform: scale(0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.75;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: ripple 1000ms;
}
@-moz-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
@keyframes ripple {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a  class="bg--red tx--white" ripple="ripple" href="http://www.google.de">Fail</a>
  <a class="bg--blue tx--white" ripple="ripple"  href="http://www.google.de">Info</a>
  <a class="bg--green tx--white" ripple="ripple"  href="http://www.google.de">Save</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @madalinivascua Make a Default Html Page and test it there it will not work

Comment: you need to place the javascript **after** the html or wrap your code in a document ready function

Comment: @madalinivascua If I do it, it will not show the animation in the button